# big-calendar react show event only one day per week

Tags: react-big-calendar

how can i show this event only Monday with big-calendar react

const events = [

```
{
      id: 2,
      title: 'testevent',
      start: new Date(2020, 4, 29),
      end: new Date(2020, 5, 26),


  },
```

]
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking to do, as I understand you want to show an event with a long duration only the day when it starts?
I thats your case maybe you should use the allDay?: boolean on the Event Object or just set at the end value the same start as value.

I hope it helps you.